# Как быстро загрузить список сообщений с почтового сервера?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, клиент-сервер, async-await, асинхронность

Занимаюсь разработкой почтового клиента под ОС Андроид с помощью C# и Xamarin Forms. Работа с сервером и протокол реализован, однако при создании GUI возникла проблема со скоростью подгрузки сообщений. Опыта разработки асинхронных и многопоточных приложений у меня нет, что как раз и мешает мне разобраться с этой проблемой. 
Листинг метода подргузки сообщений:

```
    private async Task<List<ImapMessageInfo>> LoadMessagesInfo()
    {

        foreach (var item in uidsCash)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var header = streamOperator.ReceiveResponse($"$ UID FETCH {item} BODY[HEADER]", s => s.Contains("$ OK"))
                    .Where(n => !n.StartsWith("* ") && !n.StartsWith("$ ") && !(n == ")")).ToList();
                if (header.FirstOrDefault().StartsWith("$ OK"))
                    //throw new InvalidDataException($"Message #{item} was removed or not created");
                    return;
                var body = streamOperator.ReceiveResponse($"$ UID FETCH {item} BODY[TEXT]", s => s.Contains("$ OK"))
                    .Where(n => !n.StartsWith("* ") && !n.StartsWith("$ ") && !(n == ")")).ToList();

                var subject = streamOperator
                    .ReceiveResponse($"$ UID FETCH {item} BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (Subject)]", s => s.Contains("$ OK"))
                    .Where(n => !n.StartsWith("* ") && !n.StartsWith("$ ") && !(n == ")")).ToList();

                MessageModel msg = ParseBodyHeader(item, header, string.Join("\r\n", subject));

                ImapMessageInfo info = new ImapMessageInfo(msg)
                {
                    Flags = GetFlags(item)
                };

                info.Message.TextHtml = this.LoadText(header, body, "text/html");
                info.Message.TextPlain = LoadText(header, body, "text/plain");

                messagesCash.Add(info);

            });
        }
        return messagesCash.OrderByDescending(s => int.Parse(s.Message.Uid)).ToList();
    }
```

Данный код позволяет не зависать графическому интерфейсу, однако сам процесс загрузки никак не ускоряет - всего 10 сообщений загружается примерно за 10 секунд. Есть ли возможность ускорить этот процесс до приемлимого для приложения времени?

Обращение к серверу происходит в методе `streamOperator.ReceiveResponse`

**UPD**: 
В моем коде есть один стрим для чтения и записи файла с сервера. При многопоточном его использовании возникает исключение `Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Bad record MAC`. Как сделать обращение к серверу многопоточным? Нужно ли для каждого потока создавать свой стрим, чтобы читать данные с сервера одновременно в нескольких потоках?

**UPD2**:
Я обновил свой код в соответствии с предложениями в комментариях.

```
private async Task<List<ImapMessageInfo>> LoadMessagesInfo()
    {

        var tasks = uidsCash.Select(item => Task.Run (async () =>
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("imap.gmail.com", 993);
            SslStream ssl = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream());
            ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("imap.gmail.com");
            StreamOperator streamOperator1 = new StreamOperator(ssl);

            await streamOperator1.ReceiveResponse("", s => true);
            await streamOperator1.ReceiveResponse($"$ LOGIN {login} {password}", s => s.Contains("$ OK"));
            await streamOperator1.ReceiveResponse("$ SELECT INBOX", s => s.Contains("$ OK"));

            var headerAsync = await streamOperator1.ReceiveResponse($"$ UID FETCH {item} BODY[HEADER]", s => s.Contains("$ OK"));
            var header = headerAsync.Where(n => !n.StartsWith("* ") && !n.StartsWith("$ ") && !(n == ")")).ToList();
            if (header.FirstOrDefault().StartsWith("$ OK"))
                //throw new InvalidDataException($"Message #{item} was removed or not created");
                return;

            var bodyAsync = await streamOperator1.ReceiveResponse($"$ UID FETCH {item} BODY[TEXT]", s => s.Contains("$ OK"));
            var body = bodyAsync
                .Where(n => !n.StartsWith("* ") && !n.StartsWith("$ ") && !(n == ")")).ToList();

            var subjectAsync = await streamOperator1
                .ReceiveResponse($"$ UID FETCH {item} BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (Subject)]", s => s.Contains("$ OK"));

            var subject = subjectAsync
                .Where(n => !n.StartsWith("* ") && !n.StartsWith("$ ") && !(n == ")")).ToList();

            MessageModel msg = ParseBodyHeader(item, header, string.Join("\r\n", subject));

            ImapMessageInfo info = new ImapMessageInfo(msg)
            {
                Flags = GetFlags(item)
            };

            info.Message.TextHtml = this.LoadText(header, body, "text/html");
            info.Message.TextPlain = LoadText(header, body, "text/plain");

            lock (o)
                messagesCash.Add(info);

        }));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        //foreach (var item in uidsCash)
        //{

        //}
        return messagesCash.OrderByDescending(s => int.Parse(s.Message.Uid)).ToList();
    }
```

Однако при обращению с сервера даже с разных стримов возникает ошибка `NotSupportedException: Вызов метода BeginWrite невозможен, если другая операция write находится в режиме ожидания`. Метод работы с сервером:

```
 public async Task<List<string>> ReceiveResponse(string query, Func<string, bool> isLastLine)
    {
        try
        {
            if(query != string.Empty)
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(query + "\r\n");
                await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string @string;
            do
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int bytesGot = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (bytesGot == 0)
                {
                    throw new EndOfStreamException("Error while reading");
                }
                @string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0", string.Empty);
                sb.Append(@string);
            } while (!isLastLine(@string));

            return sb.ToString().Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Вот так пробую вызывать всю эту систему:

```
var resp = Task.Run(() => imap.LoadMessages());
        Task.WaitAny(resp);
        var from = resp.Result;
```

Метод LoadMessages вызывает LoadMessageInfo:

```
public async Task<List<ImapMessageInfo>> LoadMessages(/*DateTime since*/)
    {
        if (this.messagesCash != null)
            return this.messagesCash;

        messagesCash = new List<ImapMessageInfo>();

        if (uidsCash == null)
            uidsCash = await this.GetExistingUids();

        return await LoadMessagesInfo();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы запускаете таски одну за другой, то есть пока текущая задача не кончилась, новая не начнется.

Попробуйте запустить их параллельно, например:

```
private async Task<List<ImapMessageInfo>> LoadMessagesInfo()
{
    var tasks = uidsCash.Select(item => Task.Run(() => {/*..Ваш код..*/})).ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);  
    return messagesCash.OrderByDescending(s => int.Parse(s.Message.Uid)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: `Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Bad record MAC` - такое исключение теперь появляется. Вот класс работы с TLS: `public 
    class DefaultTlsEncryptor : ITlsEncryptor
        {
            public Stream Authenticate(Stream innerStream, string host)
            {
                var ssl = new SslStream(innerStream, true);
                ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

                return ssl;
            }
        }` Извините за код в одну строчку, не вышло написать красиво в комментарии

Comment: Может ли такая ошибка быть связана с асинхронностью в обращении к объекту этого класса?

Comment: @VUser меня бесполезно спрашивать про ваш код внутри таска, я не понимаю, что там происходит. Я только показал, как запустить ваш код параллельно и почему он до этого работал медленно.

Comment: однако попытаться стоило, спасибо)

Comment: И всё-таки вопросы ещё есть. Разве можно использовать один Stream для записи/чтения сразу нескольких сообщений за раз? Или стоит в каждой таске создавать отдельный стрим для чтения/записи?

Comment: @VUser стрим, насколько я знаю, не может читать для нескольких клиентов сразу. То есть я бы рекомендовал отдельные стримы на таск

Comment: Только стоит все-таки синхронизировать доступ к messagesCash

Comment: немного не понимаю зачем